# How to force a dialog to front?

Tags: jdialog

I would like to display a modal JDialog OVER all standing dialogs
when it is invoked (say) by a function key.
This way I want to display a status of my application regardless
of the pile of dialogs and pop-up's already 'on the air'.
I tried to have the dialog in question 'owned' by the mainframe
and to (Frame)null without success.
The method 'this.toFront()' just before 'this.setVisible(true)'is also without effect.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for reading.
;JOOP!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be:  [code]window.setAlwaysOnTop(true)[/code]

;JOOP!